# Stored procedure change

Tags: .net, stored-procedures, ibm-midrange

So there was a stored procedure created in iSeries which returned a set of fields in the Result Set to which a new field was added recently. The result set from the SP was consumed by .NET webpages (im not 100% sure regarding this).

My doubt is that since the SP was changed, would the older pieces of .NET (or whatever) code work without making any necessary changes to consume the newly added field?

Eventually the changes to the dependent pieces of code will be made. But if the new SP is moved and the pieces of code on other platforms are not changed (that is what our Project manager wants) , is it likely to break something?

Comment: I would say yes this will break something.  Maybe PM gets lucky and it doesn't.

Comment: Without seeing code, it's impossible for us to know what might break. There's obviously a very good chance that something won't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is a definite maybe. Some times platforms that use SQL deal with named fields. PHP for example can retrieve rows from the record set into an associative array, and then use the fields they want by name. The only way that will break is if you remove a field the PHP program is trying to use. On the other hand PHP can also retrieve fields from the record set into an indexed array. In this case, there are more ways to break the application, such as moving the fields in the result set around, or adding new fields to the middle of the result set, but if new fields are only added to the end of the result set, then you won't have a problem. I am not certain if .NET provides both access methods, but I am sure that it provide indexed (positional) access to fields in the result set. So as long as you only add fields to the end of the result set, and do not reorder anything, you should be safe.

In RPG programs using RLA, it was a big deal to add fields to a file. When using SQL, not so much.

Comment: So when i pointed my concern the response was "If the signature and what it returns is same, then nothing will break" .. Not sure what an SP signature is. Anyways eager to see how this one turns out!!

Comment: Signature is probably the parameters. It is ok to ask the PM what he means by that. If you are adding a field to the result set, then what it returns will be different, but Depending on how it is used, there might be a problem or maybe not.

Comment: Oh yeah, that "Signature".. my mind went wandering in the direction of service program signatures! :P Anyways they've promised to check this for me. So ill update once I get a response.